# How to iterate multiple time with dataloader in libtorch?

Tags: c++, libtorch

```
auto dataloader = torch::data::make_data_loader<torch::data::samplers::RandomSampler> (std::move(dataset),
                                                                                      torch::data::DataLoaderOptions().batch_size(
                                                                                      config.getBatchSize()).workers(
                                                                                      config.getNumWorkers()));

for(int e = 0; e < epoch; e++){
    for(auto &batch: *dataloader){
        const auto &calTensor = batch.data()->data;
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to use dataloader multiple times without re-initialization, but the above code doesn't work.

Above code generates the following error:

> Attempted to get a new DataLoader iterator while another iterator is not yet exhausted.

How can I solve it?

Comment: That inner loop is useless. It would just use the first element of `*dataloader` over and over again as the outer loop iterates. It also doesn't do annything with the "data" you fetch, perhaps you simplified you [mre] a little too much? What is your actual and underlying problem you want to solve? Why do you think the code you show would solve that problem? And *how* would the code solve the problem?

Comment: The code is training some model with data from dataloader, and I want to print intermediate results during the training. So, I used break in the middle of inner loop, but it causes error. I want to know why above code generates the error.

Comment: So then print intermediate results inside the loop, don't just `break` the loop. As the error message indicates, you must loop over all elements of `*dataloader`, you can't do one by one. And as I said, if you `break` out of the loop and the start it over, you will anyway start over with the very first element again, not continue where you left of. That's not how a [range `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) works.